# Incorrect encoding using jruby with datamapper

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jruby, datamapper

I'm trying to get data form a 2008r2 MSSql server using jruby and datamapper.
The only problem I've got this far is correct character coding in jruby.
Database uses Polish_CI_AS collation, testing field is populated with: `"ą ę ś ć"`.
Fetching that field from within jruby results in: `"uFFFD uFFFD uFFFD uFFFD"` which are default replacement strings for utf-8.
I've tried setting the -E variable to windows-1250, it changes the characters displayed but as in Utf-8 they are displayed in the same manner. Also tried to include # encoding: Windows-1250, but it doesn’t help either.
I’m pretty sure it has something to do with datamapper or the db connection but jdbc does not supports (AFAIK) encoding variables.

**UPDATE**

My connection string: `DataMapper.setup(:default, 'sqlserver://servername/database;instance=InstanceName;domain=DOMAIN')`

Comment: Encodings are driver specific. MS SQL JDBC takes care of it automatically according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378857.aspx

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection works well with MS JDBC, datamapper uses jTDS which uses UTF8 encoding as default.

I've checked the jTDS documentation and found that I needed to add: `charset=cp1250;` property at the end of my connection string. It all works well now.